# ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, ubuntu, oracle-xe

i am facing this error when i start the oracle. I checked Oracle Home and SID. everything is set properly.

> ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

please help me to find out the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: What OS? What Oracle version?

Comment: Version: Oracle-Xe - 
Server : Ubuntu

Comment: What are `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_SID` set to, are they exported in the shell (not just set), and does the SID exactly match the process: what does `ps -fe | grep pmon` show?

Comment: ORACLE_SID = XE
ORACLE_HOME = bash: /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server
ps -fe | grep pmon shows like :
jubair    4564  3458  0 02:13 pts/0  00:00:00 grep --color=auto pmon

Comment: That looks like there's no ora_pmon_XE process, indicating the DB isn't running, but I'm not entirely clear from your question whether you're getting the error on startup or trying to access after start. Is the 'bash: ' in the ORACLE_HOME a transcription error? (does `ls $ORACLE_HOME` show the expected directory contents, or an error?) Is there anything in the alert log?

Comment: That ORACLE_HOME value looks a bit odd to me. Should just be a path. I think @Adam is correct, instance needs to be started.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That error generally means there's no Oracle instance (the processes) to connect to.  Someone needs to log in and start the instance.

Comment: I did start the oracle instance but it didn't work !

Answer (score 3):

I've just resolved this issue on Debian.

If ORACLE_HOME has a trailing slash, this error appears. If you remove the trailing slash, connection works fine.