# Oracle 11 XE on Ubuntu giving ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu, oracle11g

I am trying to setup oracle 11g xe on my ubuntu system.
I started with instructions given on http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.com/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html
 and its other link as well.
Everything works fine and database gets installed. XE schema gets created.
problem: I am not able to log into database.

when I try

```
sqlplus / as SYSDBA
```

I get

```
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Enter user-name: root
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

I have checked ORACLE_SID is XE
I have manually put root user to DBA group

everything is fine in Listener.ora. I also created initXE.ora as suggested in some blog and assigned it to DBA group and put it in classpath.

I think I tried almost everything. and nothing more comes to my mind.

question : how else can I log in?

Comment: [This page](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2378116) may be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried running sqlplus as the oracle user (*not* as the root user) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302941/ora-27101-shared-memory-realm-does-not-exist)

Comment: The OP needs to get past the ORA-01031 before they can start the instance and get rid of the ORA-27101 though?

Comment: I also faced the same problem for oracle 10g XE. suod /etc/init.d/oracle-xe restart works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your oracle database isn't running. Shared memory is what your client uses to talk to the server when you use the BEQ adapter - i.e. you're not running over the network. Check `ps -fuoracle` (assuming you named your db user oracle) if the server is up.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to log in with SQL plus

```
sqlplus {username}/{password}@//{ip}:{port}/{SID}
```

sample:

```
sqlplus test_username/test_password@//192.168.0.12:1521/val
```

Comment: Okay. That works for me. However, a clear text password on the command line? There must be a better solution, right?

Answer (score 1):

You must create a new user and then you will be able to connect

```
  $> su - oracle
  $> . goo
  $> sqlplus / as sysdba
  SQL> create user <myuser1> identified by <mypassword>;
  SQL> grant connect, resource to <myuser1>;
  SQL> connect <myuser1>/<mypassword>
```

**Edited**
To Start the instance

```
  $>sys as sysdba
  SQL>Enter password:<*****>
  SQL>startup open
```

Comment: `That error generally means there's no Oracle instance (the processes) to connect to. Someone needs to log in and start the instance.` it's not about missing users

Comment: You are right that's why I will change the posted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Connect to Oracle as sys user and Run these commands.

```
sqlplus sys/sys as sysdba
shutdown
startup
exit
```