# Getting error ORACLE not available in Oracle 11g

Tags: windows, oracle11g

I am not able to connect Oracle 11g in Windows 7. Could somebody please help me.
Below is the error message that I am getting :

```
SQL> connect system   
Enter password:   
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available   
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist   
Process ID: 0    
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

My tnsnames.ora file :

```
  XE =     
    (DESCRIPTION =   
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))  
   (CONNECT_DATA =   
       (SERVER = DEDICATED)   
       (ORACLE_SID = XE)    
       (SERVICE_NAME = XE)   
   )   
  )   

 EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =   
   (DESCRIPTION =   
     (ADDRESS_LIST =   
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))   
     )   
     (CONNECT_DATA =   
        (SID = PLSExtProc)   
        (PRESENTATION = RO)   
     )    
   )   

  ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =     
    (DESCRIPTION =     
      (ADDRESS_LIST =    
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))    
      )    
     (CONNECT_DATA =    
        (SID = CLRExtProc)    
        (PRESENTATION = RO)    
      )    
  )
```

I have started the listener service but still getting same error. Could somebody please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: you should connect like `sqlplus username/password@connect_identifier` also check `TNSPING`

Comment: Exhausted : do you mean by this command :  SQL> connect system/system@XE , getting same error.

Comment: Everything seems ok, It should work. try connecting other user except sys,system.

Comment: @Exhausted : **Below is the output of TNSPING XE Command:** :                                                                 `C:\>tnsping XE                                                            Used > parameter files: </code>C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin \sqlnet.ora                                          Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias                          Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (ORACLE_SI D = XE) (SERVICE_NAME = XE))) )`

Comment: @Exhausted : I tried with SCOTT/TIGER as well but getting same error.

Comment: [link] (http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_27101_shared_memory_realm_does_not_exist.htm) check the link this could help you.

Comment: Have you go through the article entirely ??? there is part of  'start the Windows services.' have you tried that??

Comment: @smn_onrocks : I have already added environment variables.

    **ORACLE_HOME :** `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server`
    **ORACLE_SID  :** `XE`

Comment: See these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302941/ora-27101-shared-memory-realm-does-not-exist http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_27101_shared_memory_realm_does_not_exist.htm http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/158747/

Comment: @smn_onrocks : I have checked oracle related services, they are running.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the oracle instance first. 
set up oracle_home and oracle_sid.

`export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2/dbhome_1/` (choose per env)

`export ORACLE_SID=dev`

`$ lsnrctl start
$ sqlplus '/ as sysdba'
SQL> startup`